# How to find coordinates $(x,y) $ from distance rule

Tags: geometry, vectors, analytic-geometry

I have 3 coordinates of parallelogram $A(3,\,2)\,, B(4,\,-5),\, C(0,\,-3)$ and $D(x,\,y)$

it's possible to get $x$ and $y$ (coordinate of $D$) from distance rule

Comment: The reason you're not getting answers to the intended question has a lot to do with the fact that you put no effort into showing how you attempted to solve the problem or where you got stuck. You didn't even do the first thing, which is to write down the "distance rule".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. way**

Since the diagonal halves each other, the midpoint of each coincide:

$${A+C\over 2} = {B+D\over 2} \Longrightarrow D = A-B+C =(-1,4)$$

**2. way**

$$AB = CD\;\;\;{\rm and}\;\;\; AD = BC$$

....
But this is like taking something from the left pocket with right hand.

Comment: You obviously didn't read the question.

Comment: Ok, what is the distance rule?

Comment: Most likely $\sqrt{(x-k)^2 + (y - h)^2}$.